# Pound sign not being converted to &pound; when fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, html, xhtml

Hey,
I'm fetching some data, including html, from a MySQL database.
I'm using the following bit of code to convert newlines and pound signs:

```
<?=str_replace(array("\n", '£'), array('<br/>', '&pound;'), $data)?>
```

Not particularly pretty, I admit, but that's all I need and since when has PHP ever been pretty? ;)

The newline conversion is working perfectly fine however the pound signs aren't. They come out as question marks.

I've taken a look at the ord() values of the pound signs and it's 163, which is right.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Tim

Comment: first thing to do, replace `<?=` with `<?php print`. I know it's longer, but the short syntax is pretty much deprecated now (our PHP installation here doesn't even work properly with the short syntax).

Comment: second thing to do, set your page output to UTF-8, and you won't need to worry about the pound sign entity (or indeed any entities at all, except `&`, `<` and `>`)

Comment: They're not deprecated at all and there's absolutely no problem with using them, as far as I'm concerned. You may be referring to the ASP-style short-tags, which I believe are being removed from PHP6. But that's totally irrelevant to my question.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use that. Changing charset halfway through has potential repercussions.

Comment: @Tim Does the charset of your database and the chartset of the page match?

Comment: please clarify your database encoding setting, your page encoding, and example data return by database (Please note that SO is UTF-8).

Comment: Inspect your page with Firebug or something similar and make sure the page actually says `&pound;`. If it does, maybe your browser just doesn't know how to draw it? Which would be very weird.

Comment: why not using htmlentities ? (and eventually nl2br) ?

Comment: Can't use htmlentities as there is html content within the code which I wish to return. Managed to get it sorted in the end by replacing them all in mysql. The input to the database converts them fine, so future inputs won't be a problem.

Comment: @Tim, if you've resolved the issue, you can add a new answer detailing your fix.  It's OK to accept your own answer, and it will help others who run into this trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is either create a new variable or keep the same one and change it.
**Same Variable**

```
$data =str_replace(array("\n", '£'), array('<br/>', '&pound;'), $data)
```

**Different Variable**

```
$anothervar=str_replace(array("\n", '£'), array('<br/>', '&pound;'), $data)
```

you can then echo it by

```
<?php echo $anothervar; ?>
```

*or*

```
<?php echo $data; ?>
```